# How to determine the file type of a .m file?

Tags: files-and-directories, scripting, matlab

Both Mathematica and MATLAB widely uses `.m` files, but with diametrically different syntaxes and usage. Currently WRI is moving towards the `.wl` extension, however due to compatibility reasons `.m` files aren't going anywhere soon.

Suppose I receive a `.m` file from a collaborator without much context, how shall I determine its correct association based on its content?

Comment: Here are a few ideas: 1) inspect the file yourself; 2) try to load it in MMA and see if it works; 3) email your collaborator back to ask. Unless you receive tens of these files a day, anything but a manual approach seems overkill.

Comment: Is this motivated by a real practical problem? If so, what is the actual problem? If you've ever worked with *either* Mathematica *or* MATLAB, even very briefly, it will be trivial for you to see if the file contains (or does not contain) Mathematica/MATLAB code. If you have never seen either MATLAB or Mathematica code, why would someone send you such a file with no explanation? There would be far bigger obstacles to making use of that file than just deciding which language it is written in.

Comment: One issue that comes to mind: is `blah = {1, 2, 3}` a *Mathematica* list, or a MATLAB cell array?

Comment: I was about to explain my intention with a comment but forgot it at all. I am a MMA user, collaborating with both MMA and MATLAB users. I am thinking how to write a simple shell tool to distinguish MMA and MATLAB files, therefore I asked this question.

Comment: You can just [edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/239311/edit) to include this.

Comment: [The answer by @Sjoerd Smit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239313) is very inspiring. I still wonder if this can be done without invoking a Wolfram system though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's somewhat of a meme that WL has a top-level function for everything, but it's kinda true:

```
Classify["ProgrammingLanguage",
  Import["file.m", "Text"],
  "TopProbabilities"
]
```

## Edit

To force `Classify` to pick between two options, you can use the `ClassPriors` option:

```
Classify["ProgrammingLanguage",
  Import["file.m", "Text"],
  "TopProbabilities",
  ClassPriors -> <|
    Entity["ProgrammingLanguage", "WolframLanguage"] -> 0.5, 
    Entity["ProgrammingLanguage", "MATLAB::82q2f"] -> 0.5
  |>
]
```

To get a list of all possible languages:

```
Information[Classify["ProgrammingLanguage"], "Classes"]
```

Comment: +1.  It classifies several of my MATLAB files as Python, one as Tcl. It suggested Perl or Scala for a short Mathematica .m file. Overall, it's more reliable on longer files, of course.  Is there an easy way to limit its choices to pick which of WL / Matlab is most probable?

Comment: @MichaelE2 You can use the `ClassPriors` option (see updated).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.